# How to get VoiceOver to announce selections in a SwiftUI List?

Tags: ios, list, swiftui, accessibility, voiceover

VoiceOver does not announce selections out-of-the-box in a SwiftUI list with selections enabled. Here is a mini-example:

```
 struct Book: Identifiable, Hashable {
     let id = UUID()
     let title: String
 }
 
 struct ContentView: View {
     @State private var selection = Set<UUID>()
     let books = [
         Book(title: "Anna Karenina"),
         Book(title: "Lord of the Rings"),
     ]
     
     var body: some View {
         NavigationView {
             List(books, selection: $selection) { book in
                 Text(book.title)
             }
             .navigationTitle("List Selection")
             .toolbar {
                 EditButton()
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

How do I make the list items to be correctly read out by VoiceOver (selected/unselected etc.) when the list is in edit-mode and the user can make selections?

Comment: As first and quick solution, try to use `accessibilityLabel` modifier. Create ad hoc string that VO will speak as description (label). You can also combine `accessibilityHelp` modifier, that is the "hint" message. This hint is spoken only if user leaves high verbosity. Set all "strange" things as hidden, `accessibilityHidden(true)` and set the accessibility label to the external row container.